# Can we modify the Main color for the Red theme from been rgb(164, 38, 44) to rgb(208, 0, 13)

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, theme, site-settings

We are working on a modern communication site >> and we chose the Red theme, as follow:-

[image]

but can we change the Red theme color from been `rgb(164, 38, 44)` to `rgb(208, 0, 13)`? We want the same exact theme as the built-in theme , but we just want to change the main red color code from been `rgb(164, 38, 44)` to `rgb(208, 0, 13)`?
is this possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, you can not change the default Red theme color from been rgb(164, 38, 44) to rgb(208, 0, 13).

As a workaround, you could create a custom theme using the Theme Generator Tool.

Reference:

https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-configure-and-apply-a-custom-theme-in-sharepoint-online/

Comment: thanks for the reply.. but is creating a custom theme using the above link a supported operation ?

Comment: Yes, it is official way.